# Get Other Applications Audio

Tags: android, audio-route

Is it possible to get the audio coming from a different application? I'd like to perform app specific-modifications to the audio coming from other running applications. After a lot of searching, I still can't seem to find any examples or proof that you may be able to.

Comment: I think this would be a major breach in privacy, wouldn't it? An app like this could listen in to all your phone calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Android audio stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003241/get-android-audio-stream)