# Record only device sound while recording video and mute sound recorded by mic

Tags: android, video-capture, audio-recording

I am making an application in Android and I am stuck at a part where I have to record a video that only listens to the internal device sound and not the sound recorded by microphone. I have searched a lot for this and now I am asking for help here as I could not find any relevant information on the internet regarding my topic.

If I could get any suggestion based on this issue it would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003241/get-android-audio-stream/15004013#15004013   Since then, the `REMOTE_SUBMIX` AudioSource has been added, but it requires the `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission which isn't available to 3rd party apps.

Comment: Could you please explain more about this with example? @Michael

Comment: The bottom line is that there's no way for you as a 3rd party developer to do what you want, at least not as far as I'm aware. Perhaps you can find some hack that works on some specific device(s), but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help @Michael.